# Video seeking doesn't work for files recorded from a camera using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, linux

I'm using the following command to record videos from a camera:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 -t 00:58:00 -i /dev/video0 /home/myuser/my_video.mp4
```

The problem is that the resulting video plays normally but does not allow seeking (i.e. I can't rewind or fast forward). The video progress indicator appears at the end, the timestamp is off and if you try to move it, it just restarts the entire video.

How can I solve this?

Additional information:

- If I do `ffmpeg -i my_video.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy my_video_fixed.mp4` the resulting video is fixed.
- If I grab from screen using X11grab, this problem does not show up.
- I'm using Linux.

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: Where do I find the logs? This was running as a cron task.

Comment: Where did you tell it to direct the stderr output in the cronjob? If you don't know then show your cronjob.